# Reading from a file in C line by line

Tags: c, file, io

I am trying to read a .txt file line by line in which each line has two words and two integers.

Currently I am running a loop with fscanf but I try to print the values and nothing prints:

```
while{fscanf(filename,"%s %s %d %d", first,second,&num1,&num2) == 1)
{
      printf("%s %s %d %d", first,second,num1,num2);
}
```

The file does open correctly I checked for that, so the issue is that the values are not being read in properly. Is fscanf() the function I should be using? If not I've heard maybe fgets() but I do not know how that would work if I have two strings and two ints.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read the manual page for `fscanf` to find out the correct return value to compare against

Comment: Use `fgets` to read whole line. Then scan with `sscanf` or / and `strtol`.

Comment: thanks for the advice, this is my first semester in coding and was unaware there was a manual haha. Problem was solved by changing fscanf == 1 to fscanf == 4 since there were 4 variables being matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`while{fscanf(filename,"%s %s %d %d", first,second,&num1,&num2) == 1)`

with

`while(fscanf(filename,"%s %s %d %d", first,second,&num1,&num2) == 4)`

Answer (score 1):

The return value of fscanf is the number of items read in so in your case the function returns 4 and that never equals 1 so the body of the loop doesn't execute.